# Only display tabs in action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I've just used ActionBar Sherlock to implement the android action bar on pre 3.0 android devices. I'm having one issue when I'm using tab navigation though.

Currently the action bar is devided in two rows at the top of the screen. The first row contains the app icon and app title, while the second row contains my navigation tabs. I tried to remove the top bar with actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0);, but now i still have two rows, but the top row is empty. How can I remove this top row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I recognize this was posted about a month ago, but I think I can lend a hand. Try running these three methods just after constructing your action bar:

```
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

The first just sets the AB to tabs, which I assume you've already done. The second disables the String title up top (I should note that it appears when the app first launches, but then disappears very quickly), and the third shuts off the icon with the same functionality as the previous method. I actually had the same thing you're dealing with occur in my app, but once I ran both of those methods, the extra, and blank, top-most bar disappeared.

Comment: This was how I did it, but i still had an empty top row. This was a bug with action bar sherlock, and was fixed in a new version.

Comment: It's a great approach - but unfortunately it does not work in landscape. Well, it "kind of" does, but it looks different because the ActionBar does not disappear as in portrait, but integrates the tabs. And because of that, the appearance is totally different, which is not nice. I would like to have the same background colors and the same layout (occupying the complete width) as in portrait.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i need, i also have to remove menu from it, otherwise it will display setting menu and three dot icon in right corner

Comment: Your answer works fine also on standart actionbar (not only scherlock). Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the accepted answer, Just remove `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` to get clean tab view without having any empty action bar.