# How Can we hide title bar while using action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, titlebar

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I'm trying to hide the title bar of my application but whenever I do that, I get a `NullPointerException` when accessing the `ActionBar` How do I remove/hide the title bar? Please note that I'm not referring to the title of the action bar. I'm referring to the title bar above the action bar. I'm running my application on an Android 2.3 device.

Below is my code: (My class extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`.)

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); //I get the NullPointerException here.

//...

setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564947/only-display-tabs-in-action-bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution on this one. If you declare your theme on `AndroidManifest.xml`, the title bar will go away on its own. Although, I don't why it only works when declared on `AndroidManifest.xml` and not on code.

The reason for the NullPointerException is that `ActionBar` is synonymous to the `TitleBar` on higher versions (ICS and newer). By using the compatibility library and `ActionBarSherlock`, hiding the `TitleBar` will also mean hiding the `ActionBar`.

Below is how you can set your application to use Sherlock's theme: (You should add it on the application's tag)

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

If you know how to hide the title bar on code, please feel free to modify my answer to include your answer. And if anyone can explain why it only works on the manifest file and not on code if would be nice. :)

Comment: The explanation of the code vs. manifest issue is in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15634330/392781).

Answer (score 32):

I hide the title bar by adding the following lines of code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type

Comment: @Azahar you should use getActionBar() if you aren't using support libraries

Answer (score 19):

to hide all the title bar and keep only  the action bar use this code:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

it worked for me

Comment: and if you are using menu layouts, set them as android:showAsAction="never" in menu.xml

Answer (score 8):

I was searching for an answer for this. Found one solution.

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

The above snippet will remove the tab title and slider. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

see this answer to grammatically show/hide titleBar from the ActionBarSherlock ..

[android: title bar hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285019/android-title-bar-hide)

Answer (score 0):

Arci's answer is not entirely correct. If you read the [Theming documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html), you can find that:

> The themes should be defined in your manifest for the entire application or on a per-activity basis. You may also define the theme in the code of each activity *before* calling `super.onCreate(Bundle)`. This must be done for every activity on which you extend from one of the 'Sherlock' activity base classes and intend to use the action bar.

In other words it would be enough for you to swap the first two lines of your original code:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. None of these answers worked for me, I still had a glimpse of the Title Bar showing right before Actionbar loaded.

I had to set the *Activity* theme to NoActionBar in the Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
```

And then set the theme back inside my Activity right before setContentView():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Custom);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

This still loaded my custom theme and I no longer see a glimpse of the Title bar when activity loads

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin. You can use below.

```
ActionBar.Hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_NoActionBar);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <activity android:name=".xxxxxActivity"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"/>
```