# android: title bar hide

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, titlebar

I have this activity made with actionBarSherlock. Is it possible to hide title of activity (not only text but the title bar) I tried:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

but it hides tabs too.

Picture:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/q71/1017267_10200157522600680_915484448_n.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.You must call [setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode%28int%29) to make the tabs visible

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

2.You must disable the activity title by calling [setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29)

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

3.You must disable application home affordance by calling [setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29)

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

This way should able to able to get a look like [this](http://i.minus.com/iqS8T4EDuLxwv.png) in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these possibly?

add this to the manifest file under application:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

or in your activity:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

It worked for me hope it will help you out. 
And this will give result like [this](http://i2.minus.com/iqS8T4EDuLxwv.png)